# Working with results of api in json array

Tags: php, json

I am using json to process a 3rd party api based on post code results.  So far I have got

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context))
```

which provides the following results from a print_r:

```
stdClass Object ( [result] => stdClass Object ( [copyrightNotice] => © 2013-2014 StreetCheck. All Rights Reserved. Contains Ordnance Survey, Royal Mail, National Statistics and Land Registry data © Crown copyright and database right 2014. [postcode] => SN5 5RF [point] => stdClass Object ( [latitude] => 51.564896985 [longitude] => -1.837017086 ) [street] => Percheron Close [street2] => [locality] => Shaw [locality2] => [postTown] => Swindon [fullLocation] => Percheron Close, Shaw, Swindon, SN5 5RF [country] => England [outputArea] => E00078711 [largeUser] => [active] => 1 [ward] => stdClass Object ( [code] => E05002164 [name] => Shaw and Nine Elms ) [constituency] => stdClass Object ( [code] => E14000947 [name] => South Swindon ) [region] => stdClass Object ( [code] => E15000009 [name] => South West ) [commentary] => Percheron Close in Shaw is in the South West region of England. The postcode is within the Shaw and Nine Elms ward/electoral division, which is in the constituency of South Swindon. [urbanClassification] => Urban ) [message] => OK [success] => 1 )
```

Where the code above is the result from json.

How do I set the value of postcode to $postcode...

I have tried:

```
$postcode = $json['result']['postcode'] or [0]['postcode']
```

and got Fatal error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in.

Could someone put me on right path please.

Answer (score 0):

These are standard objects not arrays.

```
           $json->result->postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your code the same, convert to php array.

```
//                                                                   vvvv
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context), true);
```

this should fix you up.

Answer (score 0):

As in case of your API response results in object of type stdClass.

So the result is in the form of object but not in the form of Array.

Read result like this :

```
   <?php
   $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context));

   $json->result->postcode;
   ?>
```

For reference visit : http://www.academia.edu/4092169/Get_data_from_string_with_JSON_object_in_PHP